# 404 Error when viewing ASP.NET asmx file using IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

When I right-click on my app's asmx pages and choose "View in browser" it shows a 404 error "The resource cannot be found". I am using Visual Studio 2013. I'm not sure if that might be related, but I had clicked on my project properties\Web and  clicked the "Create Virtual Directory" button.

This is happening on a new dev machine I am setting up. On my current machine I am not seeing this issue. The web.config files are the same on each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a misconfigured Virtual Directory in the IIS Express config file: applicationhost.config. Somehow my asmx file actually had it's own entry in there.